# Rails Mailer is it necessary to set routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm learning how to use Action Mailer.

I have read several tutorials, and mostly they don't mention anything about setting routes.

I have created a `my_mailer` with:

```
def send_email
end
```

and a view on `views/mailers/send_email`.

I saw that when I run `rails g mailer my_mailer` no routes are created.

I tried also `rails g mailer my_mailer send_email` which creates the views but doesn't add anything on routes.

When i go to `localhost:3000/mailers/my_mailer/send_email`, I get a no routing error. Is it because I haven't added any routes or should I look somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no routes to create.

To send mail, You can call

```
MyMailer.send_email(arguments).deliver
```

in app/*_controller.rbs' action.